# hide and show element with checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change div with checked not use useState() because i retrieve the data with useContext

```
export default function Moa() {
  const { ppsps } = useOutletContext<OutletPpspsContext>();
  const { moa } = ppsps.generalInformation;
  let hasMoaDelegate = !!moa?.isDelegatedProjectOwnerContacts;
  let hasMoaAssistant = !!moa?.isAssistantProjectOwnerContacts;

  function onCheckedChange(checkedElement: CheckedElement) {
    const { id } = checkedElement;
    if (checkedElement.checked) {
      switch (id) {
        case 'moaDelegate':
          hasMoaDelegate = true;
          break;
        case 'moaAssistant':
          hasMoaAssistant = true;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
return <div>
<GroupCheckbox
        onCheckedChange={onCheckedChange}
        className="flex gap-8"
        onlyChangedItem
        onlyValues={false}
      >
        <InputCheckbox
          id="moaDelegate"
          name="moaDelegate"
          defaultChecked={hasMoaDelegate}
        />
        <InputCheckbox
          id="moaAssistant"
          name="moaAssistant"
          defaultChecked={hasMoaAssistant}
        />
      </GroupCheckbox>
{hasMoaDelegate && (
        <p>moa delegate<p>
      )}
{hasMoaAssistant && (
        <p>moa assistant</p>
      )}
</div>
```

i expect when i check the checkbox show the div if is true and hide when i unchecked is false not use useState() because i retrieve data with context

Comment: try using `.hidden{display:none}.visible{display:block}`

Comment: @iDibya.com, answers go down there. Guesses shouldn't be put in comments.